# Migrating to ECS Fargate from EKS

Tags: nginx, graphql, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm currently in the process of migrating 3 applications from Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) to ECS Fargate. Each application is built with Node JS .The current setup seems to be only 1 load balancer in front of one application and the other two applications are accessed through that one load balancer. This is currently how all three applications is accessed:

**first_app.example.com**

**first_app.example.com/second_app**

**first_app.example.com/third_app**

The front end of each application is being powered by an nginx proxy in EKS. I'm not entirely sure if I need nginx to be in ECS Fargate because the application load balancer I'm planning on to use will have an SSL cert integrated with it for redirects to HTTPS from HTTP. I'm a little unclear how to approach moving these applications to Fargate. Additionally, the third app has 3 additional functions:

Apollo GraphQL (abstraction layer between the front end & back end)

CSV

File Manager

This functionality also needs to be implemented on the Fargate side.

Currently I have setup one ECS Fargate cluster, one ECS Service, and one task definition. The task definition currently has the following 7 ECR images:

**app_one_front_end**

**app_two_front_end**

**app_three_front_end**

**app_three_csv_job**

**app_three_file_manager_job**

**app_three_graphql**

**nginx** ??

All of these images are stored in ECR. However I don't believe I need nginx in this Fargate cluster.

I'm a little unsure how to approach the architecture for this set of applications. It seems I can only have one task definition running on a service, that's why all containers were implemented into one task definition. The service can then be associated with an application load balancer where I set path based routing to access each application.

Any advice on how to approach this migration would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each Kubernetes Replica Set should be converted to an ECS Service. Each Kubernetes Pod would be converted to an ECS Task.

- Kubernetes Replica Set == ECS Service
- Kubernetes Pod == ECS Task

If you had multiple Replica Sets in Kubernetes, in order to scale your pods independently, then in order to have the same scalability in ECS you would configure them as separate services with independent scaling configurations.

You are correct in that you probably don't need the Nginx container in ECS.

> It seems I can only have one task definition running on a service, that's why all containers were implemented into one task definition.

Services can communicate with each other. You would enable [ECS Service Discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) to facilitate that. However it is fine to have them all in the same Task/Service if they don't need to be scaled out independently.

Also, multiple services can be associated with a single Application Load Balancer by creating different listener rules in the load balancer that map to different Target Groups, if that is something you need. You might need to have multiple Target Groups even if you only have a single ECS Service, because you will need to map different load balancer listeners to different containers in your task. That basically allows the Application Load Balancer to perform the job that Nginx was doing in Kubernetes.