# Migrating application from EKS to ECS Fargate

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am looking for guidance on migrating an application from AWS EKS to ECS Fargate.

The application contains three microservices (.net core, angular) with backend as Neptune.
So, there are three important deployments along with other K8S deployments (coredns, external dns, ingresses, nginx, helm releases)
There is no persistence  volume.
K8S version : 1.22

I am referring to [Migrating to ECS Fargate from EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74738533/migrating-to-ecs-fargate-from-eks).

Are there any other guidelines or an example which I can follow and do hands-on on a small scale first?
e.g. - will there be any change in docker file required?

Appreciate any suggestions/information on known challenges/references.

Ref : [Migrating to ECS Fargate from EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74738533/migrating-to-ecs-fargate-from-eks)

Comment: Your question is probably too broad for this site. Are there specific things you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tool](https://github.com/awslabs/specctl) you can use to migrate Kubernetes objects, e.g. Deployments, to ECS. It's not perfect because there k8s objects and settings that have no analog in ECS. The good news is you should not have to re-write your Dockerfiles. You may, however, need to do additional work to enable service discovery, health checks, application autoscaling, etc. Helm doesn't work with ECS configuration files. I recommend looking at TF, CloudFormation, or CDK instead.